# Why do I not get a warning when I print a variable without initialising a value? (CodeBlocks 20.03)

Tags: codeblocks, compiler-warnings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpcq9.png)when I compile and run the code I see 4200987 being printed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mXMy.png)This is what I get when instead I should be getting a warning. What do I change and where do I make these changes to start getting warnings?